# SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xff' when running C executable using subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, ascii

I need to run a program and make use of its console output in a python script by use of subprocess module.
Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding=utf-8

from __future__ import unicode_literals
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT


# Check the code by running linux list command
p = Popen(["ls", "-l"], stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1)

with p.stdout:
    for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
        print line
p.wait() # wait for the subprocess to exit

# Run the C hello world program
p = Popen([sys.executable, "hello_C"], stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1)

with p.stdout:
    for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
        print line
p.wait() # wait for the subprocess to exite
```

"ls -l" output is shown in Python console with no problems. I am assuming the code related to subprocess and reading stdout is correct. But when I try to run the hello_C program, which is just a hello world program, it gives the following error:

```
  File "hello_C", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xff' in file hello_C on line 2, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

Comment: `hello_C` Does not seem to be a Python file and you run it like one.

Comment: You shouldn't use `sys.executable` to run a compiled executable program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sys.executable` is the Python interpreter. Sys `hello_C` is a compiled C program, not a Python script, you shouldn't use it to run the program. Just run the program directly.

```
p = Popen(["./hello_C"], stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1)
```